# What does it mean for the Catholic Church to be inclusive?

Tags: catholicism, terminology, inclusivism

What does it mean for the [Catholic Church](https://www.stmargaretstl.org/) to be [inclusive](https://www.stmargaretstl.org/school/giving/committee/diversity/)?
Does [inclusivity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF1pLA3f7Lg&t=18s) mean that of race?

From one of the links:

The St. Louis Mosaic Project Ambassador School program encourages member schools to reinforce an internationally welcoming and inclusive culture through pledges unique to each school. St. Margaret of Scotland is proud to be an Ambassador school.

Comment: The question would benefit from including some references of web pages where a church makes such a claim.

Comment: It has exactly that in the links

Comment: In the second link that you provided, there is the following text: "St. Margaret of Scotland has long valued diversity and is continually working to improve our community’s individual and collective efforts. This call to action comes from our mission, from our tradition begun in earnest under former principal Sister John Mandeville’s leadership, and in conjunction with the U.S. bishops’ renewed call to identify racism as a sin in need of healing."  So in the case of this specific church, I'd say that race is at least a big part of what they mean.

Comment: @AlLelopath says "*It has exactly that in the links*", perhaps, but not in the question itself. Questions should be self-contained, with links provided only for purposes of verification. It's unreasonable to expect every reader to spend time reading entire documents to find the specific text that the question is asking about. Even worse, links tend to rot over time, and when those links break, this question will become useless. But with the text explicitly included here, everyone will be better off.

Comment: Point taken. I will add some text

Comment: This isn't a spiritual/religious/Christian question. The linked page makes it clear: this is Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion; it involves being a No Place for Hate school; it involves National Hispanic-Latino month and other ethnic months; Deaf History month; LGBTQ month. These aren't Catholic or Christian doctrines, but political or cultural positions. So despite it being on a Catholic school web site, it turns out not to be on topic.

Comment: @MikeSpear: Thanks for your response. I think this is correct. Please make this into an answer.

Comment: @Maverick it's still topical, the "business" of running a parochial school and policies around it have always been on topic for the site. We're not just christiandoctrine.se.

Answer (score 2):

**What does it mean for a Catholic Church to be inclusive?**

The four **marks** of the Catholic Church are that she is one, holy, catholic (as in universal), and apostolic. Being inclusive is not one of the **marks** of the Church.

Being universal, the Church welcome all races of humanity. The Catholic Church is truly global. She includes people of every nation, ethnicity, race and culture. What could possibly be more diverse than the Catholic Church?

Inclusiveness nevertheless is not one of the marks of the Church given by Christ.

> Back in the day, kiddie Catholics learned that the Church had four “marks”: The Church is one, holy, catholic (as in “universal”), and apostolic. These marks derived from the Nicene-Constantinopolitan Creed, which we recite at Mass on Sundays and liturgical solemnities. The Catechism of the Catholic Church teaches that the Church “does not possess” these “inseparably linked” characteristics “of herself”; rather, “it is Christ who, through the Holy Spirit, makes his Church one, holy, catholic, and apostolic, and it is he who calls her to realize each of these qualities” (CCC 811).
>
> You will note that “inclusive” is not one of the marks of the Church given by Christ, although “universal” is. Distinctions, as ever, are important.
>
> Universality must characterize the Church’s evangelical mission, for the Lord commanded us to go and “make disciples of all nations” (Matt. 28:19). And a certain kind of inclusivity denotes a crucial ecclesial reality: **“For as many of you as were baptized into Christ have put on Christ. There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither slave nor free, there is neither male nor female; for all of you are one in Christ Jesus”** (Gal. 3:28). Moreover, the Church is called by the Lord to serve everyone, not just the Church’s own; as historical sociologist Rodney Stark has pointed out, paleo-Christian care for the sick who were not of the household of faith attracted converts in classical antiquity, when the sick were typically abandoned, even by their own families.
>
> *Those expressions of ecclesial inclusivity (or catholicity, or universality) are not, however, what contemporary woke culture means by being “inclusive.” As typically used today, “inclusion” is code for accepting everyone’s definition of self as if that self-definition obviously cohered with reality, were inherently unchallengeable, and thus commanded affirmation.*
>
> **It is worth noting in this context that the Lord Jesus practiced some serious exclusion on occasion.** Thus his exclusion from beatitude of one kind of sinner: **“Whoever blasphemes against the Holy Spirit never has forgiveness”** (Mark 3:29). And his condemnation of the pitiless: “Depart from me, you cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels” (Matt. 25:41). And the fate of the one who tempts the innocent: **“It would be better for him if a millstone were hung round his neck and he were cast into the sea”** (Luke 17:2). And his determination to cast “fire upon the earth” (Luke 12:49) and burn out all that was contrary to the Kingdom of God. - [“Inclusion” and Catholicism](https://www.firstthings.com/web-exclusives/2023/02/inclusion-and-catholicism)

The concept of any valid definition of the term inclusivism is as yet to be standardized. It nevertheless must remain faithful to the mission of the Church established by Jesus Christ and it’s concepts on a philosophical and theological level of understandings and are to remain firm to the concept of truth, in the light of the Gospel to moral values taught by Jesus Christ, himself.

The following articles may be of interest to some:

- [Inclusive Christianity (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusive_Christianity)
- [‘Wokeness’ and ‘pseudo-religions’: Catholic colleges look for ways to challenge growing cancel culture](https://bccatholic.ca/news/catholic-van/wokeness-and-pseudo-religions-catholic-colleges-look-for-ways-to-challenge-growing-cancel-culture)
- [Diversity and Inclusion in the Catholic Church?](https://dwightlongenecker.com/diversity-and-inclusion-in-the-catholic-church/)
- [Inclusive Church, uncertain trumpet](https://www.catholicculture.org/commentary/inclusive-church-uncertain-trumpet/)

Comment: This does not answer the question